# Xcode 7.1 Simulator - Adding photos works very slow - How to fix?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, photos

I'm trying to add multiple photos to Xcode 7.1 Simulator using drag and drop and it works very slow. If you add only one file everything is ok, but multiple files freeze the simulator.

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code that you've tried and errors/issues you're having. Thanks!

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, it literally takes minutes to complete for about 10 photos. It's only copying the files, something is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line if you prefer:

```
xcrun simctl addphoto /path/to/photo1.png /path/to/photo2.png ...
```

Yes, it will take more time to add more photos.

Comment: Yes, works fine with xcrun simctl addphoto DEVICEID 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg 4.jpg 5.jpg 6.jpg 7.jpg, but drag and drop was more convenient to use

Comment: Both go down the same codepath and should take the same time.  The issue is just that Simulator.app unfortunately SPODs during the addition, but it will eventually resume.